# Conditional dot

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, punctuation

I did some changes to my LoF in order for the page number not to be printed with a dotted leader at the right margin but just with a short gap after the caption. Now I would like to have **one** dot ending the caption, which in most cases under the figure is supposed to be printed **without dot**. For that I have somewhat managed to redefine `\cftfigureformatpnum` to include a dot. But I would actually like the dot to be conditional, for the case that the caption exceptionally does end on a dot (or possibly some other punctuation), similar to how `biblatex` does.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}

%Some formatting of the figure captions
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{qquad}{\qquad}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}%
{font=small,labelfont=sc,textfont=it,format=hang,labelsep=qquad}
\captionsetup{style=mystyle}
\renewcommand*{\figurename}{figure}

%Some formatting of the LoF
\renewcommand\printloftitle[1]{\section*{#1}}
\renewcommand\afterloftitle{\vspace{\baselineskip}{\small\textsc{Figure\quad Caption}\\}}
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{\widthof{\small{\textsc{Figure\quad}}}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

%Make a dot before the page number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureformatpnum}[1]{%
\cftfigureformatpnumhook{#1}%
\hbox to \@pnumwidth{.\hfil{\cftfigurepagefont #1}}} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{something}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{something a bit longer, longer, longer, longer and longer, and longer, and longer, and longer}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{If I already have a dot it gets ugly.}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image: My figures]

[image: My LoF]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `\usepackage{amsthm}` that has an interesting `\@addpunct` macro and carry the current value of `\spacefactor` inside the `\hbox`:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

%Make a dot before the page number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureformatpnum}[1]{%
  \edef\savespacefactor{\the\spacefactor}%
  \cftfigureformatpnumhook{#1}%
  \hbox to \@pnumwidth{%
    \spacefactor\savespacefactor\@addpunct{.}%
    \hfil{\cftfigurepagefont #1}}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

However, I'd simplify the macro as

```
%Make a dot before the page number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureformatpnum}[1]{%
  \@addpunct{.}\nolinebreak\hspace{1em}{\cftfigurepagefont #1}%
}
\makeatother
```

You're interested in a fixed space between the caption text and the page number, not that this space decreases if the page number has more than one digit.

By default, `\cftfigureformatpnumhook` does nothing.

Note that `\@addpunct{.}` will add a period only if *no* punctuation symbol ends the caption text. So you can have question marks, exclamation marks, colons or semicolons and no period will be added.

Comment: In the end the dot was not needed at all. Good to know however how to do it should I need it in future. And good you made me aware of the decreasing space before the page number!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the `xstring` package, which includes a good amount of functionality for working with strings. The `IfEndWith` and `StrGobbleRight` commands were particularly useful. After including the package, I redefined the `caption` function with the following:

```
%Renew the caption command
\let\oldcaption=\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{%
  \IfEndWith{#1}{.}{
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\output]
    \oldcaption[\output]{\output{}.}
  }{
    \oldcaption{#1}
  }
}
```

I've updated you MWE to the following:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xstring}

%Some formatting of the figure captions
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{qquad}{\qquad}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}%
{font=small,labelfont=sc,textfont=it,format=hang,labelsep=qquad}
\captionsetup{style=mystyle}
\renewcommand*{\figurename}{figure}

%Some formatting of the LoF
\renewcommand\printloftitle[1]{\section*{#1}}
\renewcommand\afterloftitle{\vspace{\baselineskip}{\small\textsc{Figure\quad Caption}\\}}
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{\widthof{\small{\textsc{Figure\quad}}}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

%Renew the caption command
\let\oldcaption=\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{%
  \IfEndWith{#1}{.}{
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\output]
    \oldcaption[\output]{\output{}.}
  }{
    \oldcaption{#1}
  }
}

%Make a dot before the page number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureformatpnum}[1]{%
\cftfigureformatpnumhook{#1}%
\hbox to \@pnumwidth{.\hfil{\cftfigurepagefont #1}}} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{something}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{something a bit longer, longer, longer, longer and longer, and longer, and longer, and longer}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{If I already have a dot it gets ugly.}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

You'll notice that the extra `.` is gone where it shouldn't exist.